# Calculating a double integral of a region

Tags: integration, circles

So I would like to calculate the double integral

$\quad \iint_G dxdy $ where $ G =\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leq 1$

I got told to carry out te substitution $u =\frac{x}{a}$ and $ v =\frac{y}{b}$ and to reduce the problem to the problem
of computing the area of a circle. But unfortunately, I still can not solve this problem.

Many thanks if you can help me out!

Comment: It is the area of an ellipse with radii $a$ and $b$

Comment: Have you learned the change of variables theorem for multiple integrals?  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx